# How can I make an Activity change on screen touch and hold and changes again on release of the same hold?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to make the screen show a word when you touch and hold the screen and the word will disappear when you stop touching. I'm doing this in Android Studio using Kotlin.

Comment: Can you share what have you tried and what were the obstacles?

Comment: I couldn't find anything to try that I thought could work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener) with two `MotionEvent`s.

`MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` - for pressed gesture.

`MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` - indicate when pressed gesture has finished.

set this listener on your root view in your `Activity`, and on each event hide/show your `TextView`.

for example:

```
myRootView.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
    when (event.action) {
         MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> showTheWord()
         MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> hideTheWord()
    }
    true
}
```